# How does the Ripple recovery key work?

Tags: ripple, wallet-recovery

I want to understand the process that occurs when a recovery key is used with Ripple.

Can anyone explain either the old process (wallet) or the new process (trade)... there was a massive change in how this works requiring a migration of previous XRP and I'm trying to see how this all ties together.